# SSL Cert Issues with Proxy Server Configuration

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

Running into an issue when applying an **SSL cert** to one of our **reverse proxy servers** - "**This server could not prove it is <*servername*>**". I think I might be confusing some of the **SAN settings** on the cert as well as server host names, dns, etc. Here's some background on my environment.

- 2 Linux servers running **Apache** set as reverse proxies - proxy1 and proxy2
- Reverse proxies are in front of various Azure web apps
- 1 Azure Load Balancer (**Basic Tier**) - proxy1 and proxy2 are part of the backend pool (proxy2 is powered off for now until I get this working on proxy1)
- Linux proxy servers have DNS entries (proxy1.local and proxy2.local) but they are **not domain joined**
- DNS record created for **Azure LB resource** with static IP assigned, ex: app-env.local

I created an ssl cert using **openssl** on proxy1 and set the **CN to app-env.local**. I also added **proxy1.local as a SAN** record. When I add the .crt and .key files to Apache configs I get the cert warning mentioned above.

Does the **CN on the ssl cert have to match the host name of the server**? Ideally I'd be able to have **one ssl cert** for app-env.local and apply it to each proxy server. I tried adding the **IP assigned to the Azure LB as a SAN** as well but no luck with that.

Any help or guidance to clear this up would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My issue had nothing to do with the LB in my environment since we're not SSL offloading. Adding individual certs/keys to each proxy server in with a CN value set to the FQDN (prox1.local, proxy2.local), along with the same SAN values (app-env.local) set on each certificate resolved my issue.